# 'int' object has no attribute 'recv'

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, сокет

Пытаюсь сделать при помощи потоков одновременное двух функций, выдает ошибку типа данных, хотя вне функции оно не выдает ошибки. Что я делаю не так?

```
import socket
import threading

conn = 0
addr = 0

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.bind(('', 1707))
sock.listen()

def connect():
    global conn
    global addr
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    print ('Подключился:', addr)

def request_data():
    data = conn.recv(1045)
    print(data)

connect_thread = threading.Thread(target=connect)
request_data_thread = threading.Thread(target=request_data)

connect_thread.start()
request_data_thread.start()

sock.close()
```

Comment: Вне функции где именно? Вы пытаетесь к числу 0 приложить функцию recv(), которой у чисел нет. Об жтом вам и сообщает текст ошибки.

Comment: Если убрать обнуление, то выдает Exception has occurred: NameError
name 'conn' is not defined

Comment: Очевидно, вы пытаетесь делать recv до того, как соединение вообще начнёт существовать.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка `'int' object has no attribute 'recv'` возникла из-за того, что у вас в `request_data()` вызвали для `conn = 0`, т.к. вы ожидали что один поток отработает код, инициировав глобальную переменную `conn`, а второй с нею будет работать.

Это называется гонка потоков -- вы одновременно запустили два потока, причем сначала должно один выполниться, после второй.

Текущая реализация сервера нерабочая, давайте покажу пример рабочей реализации, немного доработав код из вопроса.

Этот сервер запущен в главном потоке, а все новые подключения обрабатывает в отдельных потоках:

```
...

def process_connect(conn, addr):
    print("New connection from:", addr)

    while True:
        data = conn.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break

        print(data)

    print('Finish connection.')


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

sock.bind(('', 1707))
sock.listen()

while True:
    conn, addr = sock.accept()

    thread = threading.Thread(target=process_connect, args=[conn, addr])
    thread.start()
```

Добавил клиентов:

```
import socket
import threading
import time


def dos(name):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.connect(('localhost', 1707))

    while True:
        sock.sendall(name.encode('utf-8'))
        time.sleep(0.3)


for i in range(5):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=dos, args=['Client_' + str(i)])
    thread.start()
```

В консоли сервера будут сообщения вида:

```
New connection from: ('127.0.0.1', 64842)
b'Client_0'
New connection from: ('127.0.0.1', 64843)
b'Client_1'
New connection from: ('127.0.0.1', 64844)
b'Client_2'
New connection from: ('127.0.0.1', 64845)
b'Client_3'
New connection from: ('127.0.0.1', 64846)
b'Client_4'
b'Client_2'
b'Client_3'
...
```

---

**PS.**

Кст, ваш код можно доработать, чтобы теоретически он работал. Задав последовательный запуск потоков.

Тогда, сначала отработает `connect_thread` и только после этого запустится `request_data_thread`:

```
connect_thread.start()
connect_thread.join()
request_data_thread.start()
request_data_thread.join()
```

Comment: Оно понятно, но мне нужно что бы в любой момент клиенты могли подключаться к сокету, и одновременно передавать данные. Что-то похожее по функционалу на многпользовательский текстовый чат

Comment: @Дорсау, в моей реализации клиенты могут одновременно подключаться к серверу. Но `conn.recv(1045)` будет плохой практикой, если клиенты будут больше байтов отправлять, поэтому этот момент принято в цикле обрабатывать, складывая считанные данные в массив байтов. И мне кажется, что я ответил на ваш вопрос :) Если у вас есть конкретные вопросы по реализации чата, то это тема отдельного вопроса

Comment: Но они не могут одновременно пердавать данные, сервер после получения данных ждет нового подключения

Comment: @Дорсау, почему вы решили, что  клиенты не смогут одновременно передавать? Сервер ждет новое подключение, т.к. текущее завершилось, т.к. клиент закрыл соединение, закончив передачу данных

Comment: Они могут, но после первого sock.send сервер уже не получает данные, код клиента: `import socket

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('178.237.176.129', 1707))
print(socket.gethostname())


while True:
    data = input('>>')
    sock.send(data.encode())
    print(data)

`

Comment: @Дорсау, согласен, клиенты только одну порцию передадут, но это не отменяет того, что подключение клиентов будет асинхронным. Проверьте ответ, добавил в обработчик подключения сервера цикл и добавил пример клиентов